# MAMP PRO vs VHX7 vs AMPPS vs Native OSX config

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, config, mamp

I didn't find much on the net and that why i would like to ask your point of views regarding setting up a local web environment on an iMac

1- Which of the mentioned apps is recommended to install on a Mac, which is low in resources.

2- Does MAMP or AMPPS use the native OSX apache and PHP, or do they install their own versions?

Thanks in advance for your cooperation
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

MAMP and VHX7 each installs its own server software, not the default macOS versions.

Comment: Thanks Greg for your reply. I ended up using MAMP pro and I'm pretty satisfied with it, it even allows setting a NGINX environnement... cheers